# WP error when setting cookie

Tags: wordpress, session, cookies

I get this error when trying to set a cookie on a WP page.

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by(...)
```

Any help here? It worked fine when I did the php outside of wordpress, but when I move it in, it broke. Nothing special about the cookie(very basic).

So how do I get the cookie to set?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the cookie before any output is sent to the browser.  In your theme's `functions.php` file, add the following hook:

```
add_action('init', 'my_cookies');
function my_cookies(){
    // set cookie here
}
```

The `init` hook runs before your template files (`header.php`, etc) are included.  If you try to put your cookie code inside `index.php` or `single.php` or whatever template file, you would have to make sure it goes BEFORE `get_header()`.  Once `get_header()` runs, you've already sent data to the browser, and you cannot modify the headers (which is necessary to modify cookies).

Its possible you are leaking output somewhere else in your code, before the cookie code.  If you even echo a space: `echo " "` somewhere before your cookie code, you'll get that error.  If you have a closing php tag `?>` with a space after it in one of your files, this gets sent to the browser, and you'll get that error.